# Css file doesn't affect after editing in SharePoint Online

Tags: css, sharepoint-online

I has a css file named styles.css and it was loaded in masterPage of sharepoint .I change this css file  but not working. I make sure this css file already loaded in html page.I also clear cache but I don't know why it doesn't affect when I edit. Please help me, thank you so much!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to modify the online master page directly.
Firstly, you need to check if the CSS file is really imported.

[image]

Secondly,if the file is not imported, classic page you could upload CSS here.[image]

modern page we should upload CSS with SPFX,here is a  tutorial: https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss.
If the file is imported, first check whether the content of the file is displayed normally (excluding problems caused by encoding), then you can add ‘! Important’ after the style.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping! But in my case, it's not effect. I had a css like .div { width: 100% !important;} in styles.css file and I already removed it but not effect. When i f12, i still see this css. I want to remove this css. I already cleared cache

Comment: Which way do you import CSS?